# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3) - Regex Matching - Python

Tags: python, regex

In my `Python` code, I've a string and trying to find if string contains a specific pattern (Name(s) following by number). For this I am using `re.match` then `groups()` it to get required result like this.

```
authors_and_year = re.match('(.*)\. (\d{4})\.', line)
texts, authors, year = authors_and_year.groups()
```

so If I have a string like this

> Regina Barzilay and Lillian Lee. 2004. Catching the drift: Probabilistic content models, with applications to generation and summarization. In Proceedings of NAACL-HLT.

It will return me this (**As Expected**);

```
('Regina Barzilay and Lillian Lee. 2004.', 'Regina Barzilay and Lillian Lee', '2004')
```

But in some cases, I've strings like this;

> J. Cohen. 1968a. Weighted kappa: Nominal scale agreement with provision for scaled disagreement or partial credit. volume 70, pages 213–220

or this;

> Ralph Weischedel, Jinxi Xu, and Ana Licuanan. 1968b. A hybrid approach to answering biographical questions. In Mark Maybury, editor, New Directions In Question Answering, chapter 5. AAAI Press

Where Year has an alphabet with it, **so the upper regex failed here**. And to handle this scenario, I'm trying to add a new regex with it like this;

```
authors_and_year = re.match('((.*)\. (\d{4})\.|(.*)\. (\d{4})(a-z){1}\.)', line)
texts, authors, year = authors_and_year.groups()
```

But it gives me this error;

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

When I checked `authors_and_year` value, it was like this;

```
('Regina Barzilay and Lillian Lee. 2004.', 'Regina Barzilay and Lillian Lee', '2004', None, None, None)
```

I don't know from where last 3 `None` values are coming. Can anyone guide me what I'm doing wrong here??

Comment: you have more groups because of the "or" condition and the nested group in the right part

Comment: so how could I get the matching group only??

Comment: maybe with 2 regexes one after the other if the first regex fails try the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex can be reduced to this `((.*)\.[ ](\d{4})[a-z]?\.)`
which makes the letter after the year optional while keeping the 3 capture groups.

Comment: Yes, it actually worked with a minor change. Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

That's the way groups work with `|`. `None`s are coming from the second alternative. See:

```
>>> re.match('(foo)|(bar)', 'foo').groups()
('foo', None)
>>> re.match('(foo)|(bar)', 'bar').groups()
(None, 'bar')
```

You can filter out non-matches:

```
>>> [group for group in re.match('(foo)|(bar)', 'foo').groups() if group is not None]
['foo']
>>> [group for group in re.match('(foo)|(bar)', 'bar').groups() if group is not None]
['bar']
```

Or you can use named groups:

```
>>> match = re.match('(?P<first>foo)|(?P<second>bar)', 'foo')
>>> res = match.groupdict()["first"] or match.groupdict()["second"]
>>> res
'foo'
>>> match = re.match('(?P<first>foo)|(?P<second>bar)', 'bar')
>>> res = match.groupdict()["first"] or match.groupdict()["second"]
>>> res
'bar'
```

This code will not work if empty matches (group = empty string) are possible; you'll need to do something like

```
...
res = match.groupdict()["first"]
if res is None:
    res = match.groupdict()["second"]
```

Comment: Ahan..but how could I get the matching group only??

Comment: Maybe there's some magic inside `re` module, but the first thing which comes to mind is to do something like `[group for group in match.groups() if group is not None]` to filter out non-matches.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting another way to solve my problem. But for now, Maxt8r's solution worked for me.